# If Then statement - Tableau with multiple conditions

Tags: calculated-field, tableau-api

If, Then, ElseIf statement with two fields where one field has two values to be TRUE

The Lead Age and Lead Status where two statuses and both of them should be true. Tried OR, tried AND, tried adding parenthesis.

```
IF [Lead Age] >3 AND [Lead Status] = "A. Open" THEN "Open"

ELSEIF ([Lead Status] = "B. Attempting to Contact" OR [Lead Status] = "C. Contacted") AND [Lead Age] >30 THEN  "Inactive"

ELSEIF ([Lead Status] = "B. Attempting to Contact" OR [Lead Status] = "C. Contacted") AND [Lead Age] <30 THEN  "Active"

ELSEIF [Lead Status] = "N. Nurture" OR [Lead Status] ="Disqualified" THEN  "Disqualified"

ELSE "Other"

END
```

Expected Result ->

If Lead Status is Attempting to Contact and also Lead Status is Contacted, add both statuses where Lead Age is also >30 days

I tried the below as well:

```
IF [Lead Status] = "N. Nurture" OR [Lead Status] ="Disqualified" THEN  "Disqualified"

ELSEIF ([Lead Status] = "B. Attempting to Contact" AND [MQL Age] >30) OR ([Lead Status] = "C. Contacted" AND [MQL Age] >30) THEN  "Inactive"

ELSEIF ([Lead Status] = "B. Attempting to Contact" AND [MQL Age] <30) OR ([Lead Status] = "C. Contacted" AND [MQL Age] <30) THEN  "Active"

ELSEIF ([Lead Status] = "A. Open" AND [MQL Age] >3) THEN "Open"

ELSE "Other"

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Below condition works for me:

```
If ([Lead Age] > 30 and 
([Lead Status] = 'Attempting to Contact' or [Lead Status] = 'Contacted')) THEN
'Yes'
ELSE
'No'
END
```

[image]

Comment: No, it's not working for me. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @Niels Henkens: I am not clear what have you edited. Could you please explain?

Comment: I just formatted you code part so that it shows as a (grey) code block and I edited the image so that it shows directly in the post instead of as a link.

Comment: @NielsHenkens, Ok. Thanks.